# Wave function evolution of an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

In many basic quantum mechanics books the wave packet of an electron is described. It will say that the wave packet will broaden as time evolves because of dispersion. But suppose the electron just sits there or moves with constant speed: how can the wave packet broaden? Because nothing real changed.

Comment: It is a free particle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_particle#Quantum_free_particle

Comment: You express doubt that certain quantum phenomena have ever been observed. Can you present arguments other than not knowing of any such observations?

Comment: Behind the theory, there is a network of millions of experimental results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for electrons to "just sit there" or "move in constant speed" in quantum mechanics, but this imposes some severe restrictions. In particular, both of those are statements about the electron's velocity (i.e. that the electron has a well-defined velocity, which is equal to zero in the first case) and therefore statements that it have a well-defined momentum, with a vanishing momentum uncertainty. And that means, because of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle in its form $\Delta x \geq \hbar/2\Delta p$, that the electron must occupy all of space. These are, mathematically speaking, reasonably-well-defined states, the plane waves
$$
\psi(\mathbf r,t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3/2}}e^{i\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf r/\hbar} e^{-i\frac{\mathbf p^2}{2m}\frac{t}{\hbar}},
$$
but they are not normalizable and they do not represent valid physical states. And, moreover, that 'wavepacket' cannot broaden because it is already as broad as it could possibly be.

If you have a physical wavepacket, on the other hand, with a finite extent, then the HUP demands that it have a nonzero momentum uncertainty, so it has components moving at different velocities which will naturally broaden the wavepacket.

Comment: I know what you said which are in the books,and by sit/move I meant sit/move as a wave packet,that's not the point here.But now I think the real problem is ,all the "plane wave/wave packet/and sit/moving electron" thing are all concepts in our thoughts,the real important thing is experiment----do we ever see evidence of the broaden packet or a sit/moving single electron?The question/discussion have little meaning if there are no experiment evidence.

Comment: *...that the electron must occupy all of space.* I feel like this isn't precise language. When $\Delta x$ is finite we don't say the electron exists within a length of $\Delta x$ of space, do we?

Comment: @AaronStevens That's a discussion for some other occasion, I should think.

Comment: @jw_ "do we ever see evidence of the broaden packet or a sit/moving single electron?" ─ yes, absolutely. Did you think that your textbook was just telling you fantasies without experimental support? The observation that wavepackets broaden is empirical, and there has yet to be a reproducible report of a particle that sits, unconfined, without its probability density spreading as per QM's predictions.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty I really think only energy levels are experiment based and others like wave function are just hypothesis...Would you please give me some link to the experiments?If experiments confirms the broaden thing,then the experiment is the answer of the question.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not particularly interested in chasing moving goalposts ─ if you're prepared to disbelieve the fact that QM is grounded in experimental reality, and that there isn't a single experiment that is inconsistent with it, without any real understanding of what the experimental basis is, then you're already on the wrong track. This broadening is routinely observed (when commissioning and benchmarking BEC and ion-trap experiments, in particular) but it is no longer routinely *reported*, and I don't have time to dig into old publications (particularly given the moving goalposts).

Comment: @ Emilio Pisanty sorry for the misunderstanding.I said"I really think" but the real meaning was "I really thought",means I know I was wrong .I'm not "prepared to disbelieve"----I'm learning ,not even have time to challenge anything.I know that QM is a verified theory as textbooks says,but not being a physicist,my knowledge mainly come from basic text books and wiki' main entries instead papers/journals.The experiment evidence there are mainly energy levels,I never saw an evidence about time evolving wave function like broadening electron.So I thought the wave function theory is just  hypnosis.

Comment: @ Emilio Pisanty and sorry for the changing goal.Indeed now I think the most  appropriate question should be where are the experimental evidence about the broaden wave function,can you provide some links?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty If all the basic textbook does not provide a single evidence about time evolving wave function maybe they should add one someday.I mean more direct evidence e.g. measure the probability at some location and time(directly or indirectly),there are enough indirect evidence like energy levels.

Comment: @jw_ Ask that separately.

Comment: @ Emilio Pisanty : I said "I know what you said which are in the books", now I know that I didn't really know what the books said and sorry for not approve the answer until now.